# Installer for Executing Multiple Installs

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I've been to stackoverflow.com many times, but this is my first time posting here. I'll try to be as specific and to the point.

I'm in the process of converting all my PC discs into digital .iso files and there's a few games I have that are multi-install discs.

Recently I've started using Inno Setup and so far I've had a lot of success consolidating multi-disc installs into a single program executable.

The one I'm currently focusing on is the Battlefield 1942 series. It requires initial installation, multiple expansion installs, plus a major patch, plus the installing of a mod that takes multiple steps.

My question to the community is how would I pack all of the above files into one executable and have them install everything in order? If it can be done through Inno, I'd like to try that. Or if you suggest another program I can always take time to try and learn it.

I've tried making a batch file for this a while ago but it ended up kind of clunky and I really didn't like the way it turned out.

Also, is there a way to insert check boxes into Inno to choose what executables run? (this part of the post isn't as important as the above request, just kind of a bonus if possible).

Really looking forward to the community's response on this!

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, if the final result should be fully patched version with mod installed, you should build new installer that will contain that fully patched game with mod. 
You can do it easy way to find out what is changed/added by each patch, addon, MOD. 
After installation of each thing (addon/mod/etc.) make a backup copy of the installation folder and check the registry entries. 
Then just compare folders/directories and filter out specific files for each patch, addon, MOD. 
At the end you will be able to add each addon and MOD as `Components` (files and registry entries) - that will create checkboxes in the Components Selection Wizard Page.

Easiest way: 
For External Installers/3rd Party Apps at the end of installation more info to be found here: http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection

Comment: Have you ever heard the phrase "that's the one page I skipped"?
That statement is 100% accurate right now. I feel utterly embarrassed that I somehow managed to skip the "run" section of the online help guide while reading almost all the rest of it. I thought it had something to do with [Setup] or [File] part of the script.

As for consolidating the patches, a lot of the setup files use version and/or size checks and won't install properly when you try to make an all in one installer out of them. Unfortunately I've tried.

Thanks for the very fast and professional response!

Answer (score 2):

One approach you can follow is to create a *installer of installers*, where you just *pack* the installers you have now and at installation time run each in the precise order you do now to get your fully installed and patched game.

That way, you don't have to learn each file/registry key or other settings each game have, and the risk of failure if you forget to include something vital to it.

What you have to do in order to do that properly, is to learn if the current installers accept it's own configuration from command line parameters or text files (many installers do it, for example the **/silent** or **/verysilent** command line parameters to run *on the background*). Once you do, use the [run] section of your script to launch each installer passing the parameters via command line or pre-made text files, or even you can create a text file or command line parameters on the fly using the [code] section with the built-in pascal script.

If your installers don't accept parameters, you can even reach your goal to keep all in one single exe file which you can run and then configure each individual installer as it launches.

Your question is overly broad to include here a working example, but you can find guidance by studying the scripts in the `samples` directory.

As for your final question

> Also, is there a way to insert check boxes into Inno to choose what executables run?

You can use the [run] section to let the *user* select what to run at the end.

Or you can use the [tasks] section to create different `sets` of files/configurations.

A final word is to check the available flags for your install script entries, for example, `deleteafterinstall` to cleanup individual installer included among your `[files]` entries, or the [uninstallrun] section to give a unified uninstaller also.

Comment: Thanks for the response! :)
Creating an installer of installers is exactly what I need.
I haven't had a chance to write the new script. JUST got back home, but I'm in the process of doing it right now.

As I told roben I managed to COMPLETELY skip the [run] section of the online help file and feel incredibly dumb for doing so. After reading it I realized the first part of the question was unnecessary...

Your response about the check boxes was helpful, so thanks for that!

I'm going to try and get this done and I'll let you guys know if it turns out well.

Thanks again.